# MySQL: Employee Productive Hours Calculation

Tags: mysql, report

I have a requirement to calculate the Productive hours of an employee using MySQL.
Where a Bio-Metric will capture the IN Time and Out Time of the respective employee.

The Data in **emp_device_attendance** table exactly looks like below:

```
**log_date          device_id   emp_code    device_direction**
2017-09-25 19:34:14  108         400148          out
2017-09-25 14:07:13  106         400148          in
2017-09-25 13:25:10  108         400148          out
2017-09-25 10:45:03  106         400148          in
```

From the above table I need to represent a report by excluding the time that he spent "out". Means we need to present how much time he is there in office.

The Output should be look like below:

```
emp_id  date         in_time    out_time    total_hrs   productive_hrs
400148  2017-09-25  10:45:03    19:34:14    08:49:11    08:07:41
```

can someone please help me in doing this in MySQL.

Comment: An employee only enters twice on any given day?

Comment: He can have entries with multiple in and out's, every entry and exit have records saved

Comment: Then the example doesn't really adequately reflect reality.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain query.

Subquery in_timing:

This subquery is used to calculate all in time of user and on particular date. One row_number is generated whose 
values is reset if there is change in emp_code or date(log_date).

Subquery out_timing:

This subquery is used to calculate all out time of user and on particular date. One row_number is generated whose 
values is reset if there is change in emp_code or date(log_date).

Joining to result: 
Now join those two subquery based on emp_code, date(log_date) and row_number.

Now use of timediff and sec_to_time and time_to_sec you can get your required result.

I hope this will help you.

```
create table  emp_device_attendance (
  log_date timestamp,
  device_id int,
  emp_code varchar(20),
  device_direction varchar(5)
);

insert into emp_device_attendance values('2017-09-25 19:34:14',108,'400148','out');
insert into emp_device_attendance values('2017-09-25 14:07:13',106,'400148','in');
insert into emp_device_attendance values('2017-09-25 13:25:10',108,'400148','out');
insert into emp_device_attendance values('2017-09-25 10:45:03',106,'400148','in');

set @inNumber = 0; 
set @inEmpCode = '';
set @inLogDate = '';
set @outNumber = 0; 
set @outEmpCode = '';
set @outLogDate = '';

select abc.emp_code,abc.date1,min(in_time) ,max(out_time), 
timediff(max(out_time), min(in_time) ) total_hrs,
sec_to_time(sum(productive_hrs)) productive_hrs
from ( 
select in_timing.emp_code,in_timing.date1, 
min(in_timing.log_date)  as in_time, 
max(out_timing.log_date)  as out_time,
time_to_sec(timediff(max(out_timing.log_date), min(in_timing.log_date) )) productive_hrs
from 
( select device_id,emp_code,device_direction, date(log_date) as date1, log_date ,
  if(@inEmpCode = emp_code and @inLogDate = date(log_date) , @inNumber := @inNumber + 1 ,@inNumber := 1) row_number,
  @inEmpCode := emp_code ,@inLogDate := date(log_date)

  from emp_device_attendance
  where  
    device_direction = 'in'
    order by log_date, emp_code
) in_timing join 
(select device_id,emp_code,device_direction, date(log_date) as date1, log_date ,
  if(@outEmpCode = emp_code and @outLogDate = date(log_date) , @outNumber := @outNumber + 1 ,@outNumber := 1) row_number,
  @outEmpCode := emp_code ,@outLogDate := date(log_date)

  from emp_device_attendance
  where  
    device_direction = 'out'
    order by log_date, emp_code ) out_timing on in_timing.row_number = out_timing.row_number
and in_timing.emp_code = out_timing.emp_code
and in_timing.date1 = out_timing.date1

group by in_timing.emp_code,in_timing.date1
,in_timing.row_number ) abc
group by abc.emp_code,abc.date1
```

Comment: Good grief, that's a lot of query :-(

Comment: @Strawberry I thought so, but it handles all test cases because of that it has that much query.

Comment: @FahadAnjum The query is returning same for Total and Productive Hours, which will not be the case. Productive hours will differ when we have multiple in and out in same day.

Comment: Can you please add your test data once ? It is showing different for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea. I should say that this makes certain assumptions about your data set, that may or may not be true, but it should give you the idea...

```
SELECT emp_code
     , DATE(log_date) dt
     , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(subtotal)) t 
  FROM
     ( SELECT x.emp_code
            , x.log_date
            ,TIME_TO_SEC(x.log_date)-TIME_TO_SEC(MAX(y.log_date)) subtotal 
         FROM emp_device_attendance x 
         JOIN emp_device_attendance y 
           ON y.emp_code = x.emp_code 
          AND y.log_date < x.log_date 
          AND y.device_direction = 'in' 
        WHERE x.device_direction = 'out' 
        GROUP 
           BY x.emp_code,x.log_date
     ) a
 GROUP 
   BY emp_code,dt;
```

Comment: Have you tested it for more than two in and out ?

Comment: @FahadAnjum I don't need to ;-) - but it does assume that there is a (same day) 'out' for every 'in'